# Why does this code not crash the cin? char entered for an int variable c++

Tags: c++, crash, char, int

could someone explain to me why my codes does not cause an infinite loop or crash when the user enters a char for the int menu variable when asked? I have tested it and it does work correctly but would have thought it would crash... many thanks!

```
int menu;
int drawCheck = 0;
cout << "Press 1 to play a friend\n"; 

cout << "Press 0 if for some reason you opened this and now dont want to play...\n";
cin >> menu;
while (menu!= 1)                        //User enters a number that isnt 1
{
    if(menu ==0)
    {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);             //When user enters 0 the program will exit
    }
    cout << "Please enter either 1 to play a friend or 0 to exit: ";  //Will ask untill player enters either 1 or 0 
    cin >> menu; 
}
```

Comment: Did you try to print the value of menu when you type a char in the console?

Comment: While reading from stream if error occurs then an error flag is set. No reading is done until this flag is cleared. I don't know why but when this error happens, whatever the value of the value of the variable was,  0 is set to the integer variable. And as per your code it works for exit.

Comment: For more, to solve this problem [ if already not solved] and go ahead with your code, try making menu as a char type and taking input compare with "1".

Comment: Sorry if this is really basic as i am new to c++ but how would i go about making it so that once i have made menu a char variable i can input the number 1 and have an if(menu==1){//do code} work successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tested it and it does work correctly...

I'm not sure how you can claim that what it does is "correct"... what is correct if the user types a letter - to continue, or to terminate?  Why?

Anyway, given...

```
int menu;
cin >> menu;
```

From C++11 onwards, if parsing of an `int` from `cin` into `menu` fails, `menu` is set to zero, per 22.4.2.1.2/3:

> The numeric value to be stored can be one of:
>
> — zero, if the conversion function fails to convert the entire field. ios_base::failbit is assigned to err.
>
> ...(other behaviours for successful parsing num that's in/out of range)...

So, with C++11, entering a letter has the same impact on `menu` as entering `0`, resulting in your program exiting.

Before C++11, the value of `menu` after failed parsing would be undefined (even if it had been initialised), making subsequent use of `menu` undefined behaviour.  You can't reason about how undefined behaviour will manifest, though - on some particular execution of the program - it might coincidentally happen to match what you'd hoped would happen.

Comment: When i said it worked "correctly" i was perhaps being a bit naive, i didn't realise what was actually happening to the menu variable. 
What i meant was, when i typed a character the program would at least continually ask the user to input either 1 or 0 and once the user entered either of these values the program would continue to work as expected.

Thank you for your detailed answer Tony, it was very useful!